# How to set equations containing factorials?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, factorial

I recently encountered a problem involving the construction of equations involving factorials or combinatorial numbers. I recall reading somewhere (although I cannot recall the reference) that this can be a tricky subject.

In a particular scenario, the author of the problem suggested that the solution would be $x=1$. To construct the simplest equation possible with this solution, the author proposed using $x-1=0$. Subsequently, the author manipulated this equation to obtain:

\begin{align}
(x-1)^2 &= 0 \\
x^2 - 2x + 1 &= 0 \\
x(x-2) + 1 &= 0 \\
x(x-2) &= -1 \\
\frac{x!}{(x-1)!}\frac{(x-2)!}{(x-3)!} &= -1 \\
x!(x-2)! &= -(x-1)!(x-3)!
\end{align}

However, upon substituting $x=1$ into the equations, we encounter expressions such as $(-1)!$ and $(-2)!$, which do not make sense in this context.

My question is: Am I missing something, or is the author's approach incorrect? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying for here.  If you don't like expressions like $(-1)!$ then you can't claim that $x-2=\frac {(x-2)!}{(x-3)!}$ for small $x$.

Comment: @lulu. Is there a contradiction to the processus of the author. Starting from $x=1$ he wants to set an equation containing factorials. But the final equation contains $(x-2)!$ and $(x-3)!$ which are not defined for $x=1$.

Comment: Not following.  The equation $x-2=\frac {(x-2)!}{(x-3)!}$ is simply not true for small integer values of $x$ ( I am assuming that you have only defined $x!$ for non-negative integers).  But, what are you trying to accomplish?  It's not hard to solve $(x-1)^2=0$ after all.

Comment: @lulu Thanks again. I recall reading somewhere (although I cannot recall the reference) that setting equations containing factorials. I found this example in mobile application where the authors follows the given procedure to establish an equation containing factorials whose solution is $x=1$. I was almost sure that the author's method was not correct. Still I was wondering if I was missing something.

Comment: Well, what you wrote makes little sense.  Perhaps you misunderstood what you read?  The calculation you provide seems like a bizarre way to try to solve a simple equation.

Comment: @lulu. I said again. My purpose is to find out how one can set (construct) equations involving factorials starting from a supposed solution. Not to solve a given equation. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: No, it isn't.  What set of equations do you believe you constructed?  As I said, I expect you misunderstood what you read, but of course I don't know what you read and it is perfectly possible that it is flat out wrong.

Comment: @lulu To avoid extended discussion. Can you provide me references (here in MSE or elsewhere) with methods to construct equations containg factorials when the solution is supposed? Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factorial can be generalized to complex arguments using the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function): $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$. This function has poles at all non-positive integers, so the factorial of a negative integer diverges. Thus you’re right to think that this attempt at constructing an equation with solution $x=1$ is misguided, since substituting $x=1$ leads to expressions that are divergent even when appropriately generalized.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Are there proper ways to construct an equation involving factorials when the solution is supposed? For the sake of simplicity assuming positive integer solutions.

Comment: @Dimitris: There are all sorts of ways. Just one example: Write the equation as $x(x+2)=4(x+1)-5$, then replace each linear factor as you did in the question to obtain $\frac{x!}{(x-1)!}\cdot\frac{(x+2)!}{(x+1)!}=4\cdot\frac{(x+1)!}{x!}-5$.

Comment: Again thanks a lot.